# Can you explain this code to me: Public Class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {}

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to learn C#, but I feel the syntax is much more difficult to understand than something like Python.

What I think this code is doing is declaring a class called "MainPageViewModel" and trying to inherit the class "INotifyPropertyChanged"? OR is INotifyPropertyChanged a method within a class elsewhere that we are trying to access for the MainPageViewModel class?

```
Public Class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   //Code goes in here;
}
```

Comment: General naming convention for interfaces in C# start with capital i.  Seeing something like `IMotor`, you should be able to reason this is an interface for a motor.

Comment: The `:` in this context just means a class implements (for interfaces) or inherits (for classes) from what comes after. From a syntax perspective, not that difficult or complex. Your confusion is likely what `INotifyPropertyChanged` is, why you would want to implement it or how, or why this likely auto-generated `MainPageViewModel` class implements it by default.

Comment: It's worth noting that while Xamarin uses C#, they're not the same thing. Understanding standard C# syntax is completely different from understanding the conventions and default code objects created in a Xamarin project. The first is a language, the second is more akin to a framework built on a language. If you're just starting out with C#, jumping right into Xamarin projects might be too much. Try starting with some simpler projects.

Comment: MVVM is hard to grasp and I still struggle with the concept. But what you have asked is explained clearly enough on lots of websites IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is a *Interface* the class `MainPageViewModel` inherits from.

An interface is in other terms a contract of what the class must implement if it inherits this interface.

This interface is specifically used by ViewModels in the Model-View-ViewModel pattern to notify the View that something has changed and the UI needs to reflect this change.

This interface simply requires you to implement the `PropertyChanged` event, which typically would look like:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

You could make a base class which you inherit from, instead of using the interface directly on each new ViewModel you create, such that you don't have to implement the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

INPC is an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface).  An `interface` is basically a contract that a class must implement.

the definition of INPC

```
public interface INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <devdoc>
    /// </devdoc>
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

just declares that it has one event, so any class that implements it **must** implement that `PropertyChanged` event

interfaces are a basic C# concept, and INPC is used throughout .NET, it is not specific to Xamarin